# How to update data inserted with implode together with other data?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to update all data using this code:

PHP

```html
      $query = "UPDATE tbl_section, tbl_login
                SET tbl_section.section=:section, tbl_login.section=:section
                WHERE tbl_login.sec_id=tbl_section.sec_id
                AND tbl_section.sec_id=:sec_id";
      $secUpdate = $crud->secUpdate($query,$sectionName,$edit_id);
```

crud

```html
    public function secUpdate($query,$sectionName,$edit_id)
    {
      $upSec = $this->conn->prepare($query);
      $upSec->execute(array(":section"=>$sectionName, ":sec_id"=>$edit_id));

      return $upSec;
    }
```

take a look at this picture:
[image]

If I update for example 'Mechanical Engineer'. It updates other data but not the one I inserted with implode.

How can I update mechanical together with that multiple data.. Or (implode)

Please ask if you dont get my query. Thanks!

Comment: Don't, saving a comma separated array severely limits your DB, and if you do save it put the delimiters before and after `,1,2,12,` that way you can query it like this `LIKE '%,1,%'` and not find `12` as this would `LIKE '%1%'`  Your much better off creating a second table and using JOIN

Comment: That said, in order to modify it, you have to pull the data out, explode it, merge in the new data, remove duplicates(optional), implode it then save it.  If you think you are saving work by not making another table, well your not, and your limiting the usefulness of your database model.

Comment: Thanks. I make another table for this one and use foreign key. thank you!